# Android Start Preference Activity Intent results in Exception

Tags: android

i have a problem, i want to run an activity which handles a preference dialog

```
Intent i= new Intent(getBaseContext(), PreferencesActivity.class);
            startActivity(i);
```

when i run the app i only get an nullpointerexcepltion when the activity should start. what is wrong?

PreferencesActivity looks this way:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.preference.Preference;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;
import android.preference.Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PreferencesActivity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.layout.preferences);
        // Get the custom preference
        Preference customPref = (Preference) findPreference("customPref");
        customPref.setOnPreferenceClickListener(new OnPreferenceClickListener() {

             public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
                 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                     "The custom preference has been clicked",
                     Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                 SharedPreferences customSharedPreference = getSharedPreferences(
                     "myCustomSharedPrefs", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
                 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = customSharedPreference.edit();
                 editor.putString("myCustomPref","The preference has been clicked");
                 editor.commit();
                 return true;
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: In which line do you get a NullPointerException? Please post your logcat.

Comment: how is your xml file (preferences.xml)? Might be that "customPref" is not in it

Comment: how can i copy the logcat entry? seems like eclipse doesnt support copy

Comment: Just control-c, it will copy it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe problem is in the getBaseContext(). If you use this method, you should set the context  by the constructor or by "setBaseContext" method. You can try to use "getApplicationContext", or just "this"

Comment: using just "this" won't work there as it is another class (OnPreferenceClickListener) so you should use PreferenceActivity.this or just indeed getApplicationContext()

Comment: tank you, I tried it before with MyClassActivity.this. Now I have a IllegalAccessException : access to constructor not allowed

Answer (score 0):

Try the following...

```
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {

    // Use PreferencesActivity.this for the Context used in the Toast below...
    Toast.makeText(PreferencesActivity.this,
        "The custom preference has been clicked",
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    // Use Context.MODE_PRIVATE instead of Activity.MODE_PRIVATE
    SharedPreferences customSharedPreference = getSharedPreferences(
        "myCustomSharedPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = customSharedPreference.edit();
    editor.putString("myCustomPref","The preference has been clicked");
    editor.commit();
    return true;
}
```